# Extra copy for struct member assignment from return value function?

Tags: c++, vector

After reading some posts on SO, if I understand correctly returning an std::vector by value is ok at initialization, no extra copy will be made if I do this

```
std::vector<double> fun()
{
    std::vector<double> v;
    ...
    return v;
}

std::vector<double> a = fun();
```

This is what I'm currently doing, but for "readability" reasons of my code I would like to rather have the vector in a struct:

```
struct MyStruc
{
    std::vector<double> v;
    ...
};
```

If I do

```
MyStruc A;
A.v = fun();
```

will it be costly ? Normally I would not care about this, but here I know that my vector v will eventually be quite large, like 100 millions elements. So I'm wondering what happens here. As far as I understand, there will be no copy elision since it is an assignment, but what about the move (not very clear for me) ? In that case, how can I avoid it ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think `A.v = fun();` is eligible for copy elision, because it is an assignment operator. (The compiler could still optimize it under the as-if rule although I'm not aware of whether any compiler would do that). However, `MyStruc A = { func() };` might be eligible for copy elision.

Comment: Yes, I knew that but it was not clear in my question I think. I was wondering if they was a another cheap solution left since assignment was excluding copy elision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement:

```
A.v = fun();
```

is an assignment, not and initialization, so is not a candidate for RVO -- and assignment operator *must* be called.

However, if you are using C++11 or later, `std::vector` has a move assignment operator, which will be used in this case, so it is not hugely expensive -- the memory for the vector will be transferred from the unnamed temp to the `MyStruct` field, without having to reallocate or copy the bulk of the data.

Comment: I'm using C++ 11 yes. So if I understand correctly, the move will be like copying the pointer ? And thanks for the answer, I'll go safely with the assignment then, I prefer to have clarity in the code rather than trying to find the cheapest solution.